# what is equal to JPanel (Java) in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-button

If I want add 2 `buttons` to `JFrame` in Java with each press on certain button I create `JPanel` and add this 2 `buttons` to the `Jpanel` then add the `JPanel` to the `JFrame`

But in android I tried

```
public class object extends Activity {
    ToggleButton togglebutton;
    Button button;
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layout.setWeightSum(100);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams par = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,30);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams part = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,70);

        togglebutton = new ToggleButton(this);
        button = new Button(this);
        button.setLayoutParams(par);
        button.setLayoutParams(part);

        layout.addView(button);
        layout.addView(togglebutton);
        LinearLayout lay =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lay);
        try {
            lay.addView(layout);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

But didn't work I always get exception with that

What can I do?

Or what is equal to `JPanel` in Android?

Comment: I'm guessing your exception is at `findViewById(R.id.lay);` because it can't find that id? You don't have `setContentView()` in your code... Normally you define the buttons in the XML, not add them manually via Java

Comment: What specific exception do you get? To what line does the exception point?

Comment: What is the exception and where is your xml code?

Comment: to lay.addView(layout);

Comment: that id exists in the layout.xml

Comment: You never "inflate" the layout.xml file, so you can't add or grab any elements from it.

Comment: i dont want to put setContentView()
but i added 

Class clas = Class.forName("com.kareem.alertme.object");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,clas);
            startActivity(intent);

in main activity

Comment: Then you can't do `findViewById` like you have done

Comment: if i added setContentView(any layout) it will set that layout to the screen.... i dont want that...... i want add what is in this activity to another activity layout thats it

Comment: That isn't how Activity classes work... look into Fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said nothing about "adding content from one Activity to other" in your initial post and didn't include an a logcat for your exception, but the obvious problem is not calling `setContentView` while using `findViewById`.

This code creates the activity you are trying to make.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ToggleButton togglebutton;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout rootView = new LinearLayout(this);
        rootView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        rootView.setWeightSum(100);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams par = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,30);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams part = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,70);

        togglebutton = new ToggleButton(this);
        button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Click Me");
        button.setLayoutParams(par);
        button.setLayoutParams(part);

        rootView.addView(button);
        rootView.addView(togglebutton);

        setContentView(rootView);
    }

}
```

Comment: but that code mean what will appear is only the toggle button and button.....i am not searching for that.....i am asking how to add this whole linearlayout to main layout when i press a button

Comment: in main layout there is button(add item) every time i press it ....toggle button and button should be added to the screen (its like a list)(and these 2 buttons are horizontal in 1 line)

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to JPanel for android would be the root view of your layout. I think cricket has the right solution and your getting an error beacuse your not setting setContentView(). This will set your root view to the xml layout file specified. For example setContentView(R.layout.main);.

Comment: if i added setContentView(any layout) it will set that layout to the screen....
i dont want that......
i want add what is in this activity to another activity layout thats it

Comment: @KareemElsayed - Are you trying to make a custom view, then? In that case, you don't want to use the Activity class.

Comment: if you just want to add a custom layout you can create a layout and then use  the include tag. Although I think what you are thinking of is really a fragment. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html